# Are identical Docker image layers with different parent layers stored twice?

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

Suppose I have an image with 2 layers, A and B, where A is the bottom layer and B is the top layer.

When I build a second image and replace the bottom layer A with AA, but the contents of the top layer is identical to B, does Docker store the contents of B second time in its folder structure, or does it know to reuse what it already has (I'm using overlay2)?

I understand that Docker uses its cache and if a cache miss occurs for a layer, it and all following layers will be rebuilt, but can it reuse the contents somehow?

When I push these two images, will the top layer be also pushed twice, or will the remote registry know that it already has all the contents?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated if the bottom layers are different and the preceding(top) layers will be rebuilt.
Since docker layers depends on the layers above them, the top layers will result in a different hash, and will be pushed twice.